# probability of input word

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have 2 text files containing certain sentences. I calculated the individual probabilities of every single word in both files
 
for **file1 p(A)=[(total occurrence of a word in file 1)/ (total no of words in file1)]**
 
for **file2 p(B)=[(total occurence of a word in file 2)/ (total no of words in file2)]**
 
for words common to file 1 and file 2,I used
 **p(A and B)=[(total occurrence of a word in file 1 and 2)/ (total no of words in both files)]**

Some new sentences are  provided as input.
How can I calculate the probability of input words given that the ***word occurs in file 1 or file 2 or both in (file 1 and file2)*** ?
thank you.

Comment: "for words common to file1 and file2 I used $P(A)+P(B)$" Something is wrong there. What e.g. if the sum exceeds $1$? Probabilities never exceed $1$.

Comment: @drhab edited.Thanks

Comment: So it's naive bayes approach to classifying documents then? The general approach is you produce feature vector or "vocab" which will check for presence of words from your training example in your new data. So essentially words that are not in the feature vector but present in the new data will be ignored.

Comment: @Chinny84 very true.How do i estimate the probability of each word in new data.Based on the probab available form training ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing question, but here goes.
The normal approach in Naive Bayes is to compute
$$
P(\mathrm{w}| I),\\
P(\mathrm{w}| II).
$$
where the first is the prob of word present in document $I$ and $II$ respectively. As mentioned in my comment the features are considered to be independent so we can write the following
$$
P(w|I\cap II) = P(\mathrm{w}| I)\cdot P(\mathrm{w}| II)
$$
then when new data comes in then you will obtain probabilities as long as 
$$
w_{new}\in D
$$
where D is the event space (i.e. words present in) of file I and II, then you will define a probability as above.